# Evaluating a holomorphic function at $\pi$

Tags: complex-analysis

$f(z)$ is a holomorphic function over $\Bbb C$.  $f(0)=1$. and  $|f(z)| \le 1$ for all $z \in \Bbb C$. find $f(\pi)$.

I guess intuitionally that $f(\pi)=1$. But I don't know how to prove!

Comment: What do you know about bounded holomorphic functions?

Answer (score 4):

[Liouville's theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28complex_analysis%29)